# PySpark - Explode columns into rows and set values based on logic

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, explode

Given a Dataframe:

```
+---+-----------+---------+-------+------------+
| id|      score|tx_amount|isValid|    greeting|
+---+-----------+---------+-------+------------+
|  1|        0.2|    23.78|   true| hello_world|
|  2|        0.6|    12.41|  false|byebye_world|
+---+-----------+---------+-------+------------+
```

I want to explode these columns into a Row named "col_value".  This part is fine, but I also want to apply logic to each row, so that I get a result like below:

```
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
| id|   col_value|is_score|is_amount|is_boolean|is_text|
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
|  1|         0.2|       Y|        N|         N|      N|
|  1|       23.78|       N|        Y|         N|      N|
|  1|        true|       N|        N|         Y|      N|
|  1| hello_world|       N|        N|         N|      Y|
|  2|         0.6|       Y|        N|         N|      N|
|  2|       12.41|       N|        Y|         N|      N|
|  2|       false|       N|        N|         Y|      N|
|  2|byebye_world|       N|        N|         N|      Y|
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
```

What I have so far:

```
.withColumn("cols", F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.array("score", "tx_amount", "isValid", "greeting")))) \
        .select("id", F.col("cols.*")) \
        .withColumnRenamed("0", "col_value") \
        .withColumn("is_score", F.lit("Y") if col1_type == "score" else F.lit("N")) \
        .withColumn("is_amount", F.lit("Y") if col2_type == "amount" else F.lit("N")) \
        .withColumn("is_boolean", F.lit("Y") if col3_type == "boolean" else F.lit("N")) \
        .withColumn("is_text", F.lit("Y") if col4_type == "text" else F.lit("N")) \
        .show()
```

But it gives the wrong output, as it gives the same results for every column:

```
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
| id|   col_value|is_score|is_amount|is_boolean|is_text|
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
|  1|         0.2|       Y|        Y|         Y|      Y|
|  1|       23.78|       Y|        Y|         Y|      Y|
|  1|        true|       Y|        Y|         Y|      Y|
|  1| hello_world|       Y|        Y|         Y|      Y|
|  2|         0.6|       Y|        Y|         Y|      Y|
|  2|       12.41|       Y|        Y|         Y|      Y|
|  2|       false|       Y|        Y|         Y|      Y|
|  2|byebye_world|       Y|        Y|         Y|      Y|
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
```

How can I do this after the explode to get the correct results?

Comment: what does `df.dtypes` return for your original dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want can be achieved by applying `regex` on your `col_value` to determine if it is `text,boolean,amount or score`. The code below works as long as `score` **never exceeds 1.0**, and `amount` is always **above 1.0**. If that is not the case, let me know I will update logic.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("cols", F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.array("score", "tx_amount", "isValid", "greeting")))) \
        .select("id", F.col("cols.*")) \
        .withColumnRenamed("0", "col_value")\
        .withColumn("text", (F.regexp_extract(F.col("col_value"),"([A-Za-z]+)",1)))\
        .withColumn("boolean", F.when((F.col("text")=='true')|(F.col("text")=='false'),F.col("text")).otherwise(F.lit("")))\
        .withColumn("text", F.when(F.col("text")==F.col("boolean"), F.lit("")).otherwise(F.col("text")))\
        .withColumn("numeric", F.regexp_extract(F.col("col_value"),"([0-9]+)",1))\
        .withColumn("is_text", F.when(F.col("text")!="", F.lit("Y")).otherwise(F.lit("N")))\
        .withColumn("is_score", F.when(F.col("numeric")<=1, F.lit("Y")).otherwise(F.lit("N")))\
        .withColumn("is_amount", F.when(F.col("numeric")>1, F.lit("Y")).otherwise(F.lit("N")))\
        .withColumn("is_boolean", F.when(F.col("boolean")!="", F.lit("Y")).otherwise(F.lit("N")))\
        .select("id", "col_value","is_score","is_amount","is_boolean","is_text").show()


+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
| id|   col_value|is_score|is_amount|is_boolean|is_text|
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
|  1|         0.2|       Y|        N|         N|      N|
|  1|       23.78|       N|        Y|         N|      N|
|  1|        true|       N|        N|         Y|      N|
|  1| hello_world|       N|        N|         N|      Y|
|  2|         0.6|       Y|        N|         N|      N|
|  2|       12.41|       N|        Y|         N|      N|
|  2|       false|       N|        N|         Y|      N|
|  2|byebye_world|       N|        N|         N|      Y|
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to also do this if you know the input data types:  like [int, float, boolean, string] ?   If I use the datatypes like this is it possible to zip it somehow in : `F.arrays_zip(F.array("score", "tx_amount", "isValid", "greeting"))`

Comment: @bp2010 not sure it would work in your case as you are zipping and exploding multiple data types to the same column but there could be a workaround. if you could provide more details on what you are looking for id recommend you to a open a new question

Comment: created new question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079906/pyspark-explode-columns-into-rows-based-on-the-type-of-the-column/61080196#61080196

Comment: any alternative to F.arrays_zip in spark 2.3 ?