# PySpark - Explode columns into rows based on the type of the column

Tags: python, apache-spark, types, pyspark

Given a Dataframe:

```
+---+-----------+---------+-------+------------+
| id|      score|tx_amount|isValid|    greeting|
+---+-----------+---------+-------+------------+
|  1|        0.2|    23.78|   true| hello_world|
|  2|        0.6|    12.41|  false|byebye_world|
+---+-----------+---------+-------+------------+
```

I want to explode these columns into a Row named "col_value" using the types of the input Dataframe.

```
df.dtypes

[('id', 'int'), ('model_score', 'double'), ('tx_amount', 'double'), ('isValid', 'boolean'), ('greeting', 'string')]
```

Expected output:

```
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+---------+ 
| id|   col_value|is_score|is_amount|is_boolean|is_text|col_name | 
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+---------+ 
|  1|         0.2|       Y|        N|         N|      N|score    | 
|  1|       23.78|       N|        Y|         N|      N|tx_amount| 
|  1|        true|       N|        N|         Y|      N|isValid  | 
|  1| hello_world|       N|        N|         N|      Y|greeting | 
|  2|         0.6|       Y|        N|         N|      N|score    | 
|  2|       12.41|       N|        Y|         N|      N|tx_amount| 
|  2|       false|       N|        N|         Y|      N|isValid  | 
|  2|byebye_world|       N|        N|         N|      Y|greeting | 
+---+------------+--------+---------+----------+-------+---------+
```

What I have so far:

```
df.withColumn("cols", F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.array("score", "tx_amount", "isValid", "greeting")))) \
  .select("id", F.col("cols.*")) \
  ...
```

But it gives an error about types when I try to zip the cols to use in the explode:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'array(`id`, `model_score`, `tx_amount`, `isValid`, `greeting`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function array should all be the same type, but it's [int, double, double, boolean, string]
```

How can I do this when the types of the input columns can be all different?

Comment: the problem is that "col_value" should only be of one type. which one ? string ?

Comment: it can also be in multiple columns, i just need to be able to explode it

Comment: why do you want absolutely to use `explode` ? that's a [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Its not necessary to use it.  Can be any other way too. Must be generic and using types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Sample DataFrame:`**

```
df.show()
df.printSchema()

+---+-----------+---------+-------+------------+
| id|model_score|tx_amount|isValid|    greeting|
+---+-----------+---------+-------+------------+
|  1|        0.2|    23.78|   true| hello_world|
|  2|        0.6|    12.41|  false|byebye_world|
+---+-----------+---------+-------+------------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- model_score: double (nullable = true)
 |-- tx_amount: double (nullable = true)
 |-- isValid: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- greeting: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried to keep it dynamic for any input of columns. It will take type from **`df.dtypes[1:]`** because **`id`** is not included in **`col_value`** that is why **`skipping it(1:)`**. **`Array`** only accepts **`same type`** in it, thats why we will *convert all cols to string* before applying the logic. I think it should work for your use case. You can build your **`Y/N`** cols from here.

```
df.select([F.col(c).cast("string") for c in df.columns])\
        .withColumn("cols", F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.array([F.array(x[0],F.lit(x[1]),F.lit(x[0]))\
                                                    for x in df.dtypes[1:]]))))\
        .select("id", F.col("cols.*")).withColumn("col_value", F.element_at("0",1))\
                                      .withColumn("col_type", F.element_at("0",2))\
                                      .withColumn("col_name", F.element_at("0",3)).drop("0").show()

+---+------------+--------+-----------+
| id|   col_value|col_type|   col_name|
+---+------------+--------+-----------+
|  1|         0.2|  double|model_score|
|  1|       23.78|  double|  tx_amount|
|  1|        true| boolean|    isValid|
|  1| hello_world|  string|   greeting|
|  2|         0.6|  double|model_score|
|  2|       12.41|  double|  tx_amount|
|  2|       false| boolean|    isValid|
|  2|byebye_world|  string|   greeting|
+---+------------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: This only works when the df is of type string.  
In this case the df is coming from reading a csv, and the output to df.dtypes is: `[('id', 'int'), ('model_score', 'double'), ('tx_amount', 'double'), ('isValid', 'boolean'), ('greeting', 'string')]`  
so the above will not work when the df already has its types

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Input cols could be different at each run, which is why I am trying to use the input types to dynamically give it the value

Comment: I have **`updated`** answer, and used **`df.dtypes`** to keep it dynamic for any input cols. try it

Comment: thanks again, this is the route I was trying to take.

Comment: any alternative to F.arrays_zip in spark 2.3 ?

Comment: For this case, we could use create_map but it can’t be dynamic, you would have to hard code the columns in it. Will it update if I figure out

Comment: I'll look into create_map.. I've added a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503929/pyspark-arrays-zip-equivalent-in-spark-2-3

Answer (score 1):

you can try several unions :

```py
df = df.select(
    "id",
    F.col("score").cast("string").alias("col_value"),
    F.lit("Y").alias("is_score"),
    F.lit("N").alias("is_amount"),
    F.lit("N").alias("is_boolean"),
    F.lit("N").alias("is_text"),
).union(df.select(
    "id",
    F.col("tx_amount").cast("string").alias("col_value"),
    F.lit("N").alias("is_score"),
    F.lit("Y").alias("is_amount"),
    F.lit("N").alias("is_boolean"),
    F.lit("N").alias("is_text"),
)).union(...) # etc
```