# pyspark: arrays_zip equivalent in Spark 2.3

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark

How to write the equivalent function of `arrays_zip` in Spark 2.3?

Source code from Spark 2.4

```
def arrays_zip(*cols):
    """
    Collection function: Returns a merged array of structs in which the N-th struct contains all
    N-th values of input arrays.

    :param cols: columns of arrays to be merged.

    >>> from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip
    >>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]))], ['vals1', 'vals2'])
    >>> df.select(arrays_zip(df.vals1, df.vals2).alias('zipped')).collect()
    [Row(zipped=[Row(vals1=1, vals2=2), Row(vals1=2, vals2=3), Row(vals1=3, vals2=4)])]
    """
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.arrays_zip(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column)))
```

How to achieve similar in PySpark?

Comment: You can probably test: `f=lambda x,y:list(zip(x,y))`      ;     `myudf = F.udf(f,ArrayType(StructType([StructField('vals1',IntegerType(),False),StructField('vals2',IntegerType(),False)])))`    followed by `df.select(myudf(F.col('vals1'),F.col('vals2'))).collect()` not sure hence not posting as an answer , remove the `F` prefix if you have not named the imports as `F`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `UDF` to obtain the same functionality as `arrays_zip`. Note that the column types need to be the same for this to work (in this case of `IntegerType`). If there are any differences in column types, convert the columns to a common type before using the `UDF`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def zip_func(*args):
    return list(zip(*args))

zip_udf = F.udf(zip_func, T.ArrayType(T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType())))
```

It can be used in the same way as `arrays_zip`, for example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]))], ['vals1', 'vals2'])
df.select(zip_udf(df.vals1, df.vals2).alias('zipped')).collect()
```

Comment: Did this run for you?  I see a strange error: `net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for builtins.iter)`

Comment: @bp2010: I can't try out the code at the moment (would need to wait until tonight in my timezone), but the error is related to the return type not matching the udf declaration. I changed the code in the answer, try if it works for you. (if not using an udf with `return list([list(z) for z in zip(*args)])` would most definitely work, but I don't think it's necessary to do it that way.)

Comment: Now that runs.  But, I am trying to use this function to explode the zip.  But now with this function I see the error: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: ArrayBuffer(cols).`

Comment: @bp2010: Are you sure you are using `explode`? This looks like an error from `expand`. `expand` works on structs while in this case the zip returns an array of arrays. This could be fixed by returning an array of structs (see comment by andy on the question), but it will not be dynamic to the number of columns.

Comment: Yes.  I am using `explode`.  The logic I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61087359/3213111 I was using arrays_zip to make use that it is dynamic as I need this.  Any idea how to perform this in a dynamic manner for the columns?

Comment: I would say in general this answer does not meet the requirement of `arrays_zip`; the return type being "Returns a merged array of structs..."

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating User Defined Function

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t

arrays_zip_ = f.udf(lambda x, y: list(zip(x, y)),  
      t.ArrayType(t.StructType([
          # Choose Datatype according to requirement
          t.StructField("first", t.IntegerType()),
          t.StructField("second", t.StringType())
  ])))

df = spark.createDataFrame([(([1, 2, 3], ['2', '3', '4']))], ['first', 'second'])
```

Now results with **spark<=2.3**

```
df.select(arrays_zip_('first', 'second').alias('zipped')).show(2,False)

+------------------------+
|zipped                  |
+------------------------+
|[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]|
+------------------------+
```

And result with **Spark version 2.4**

```
df.select(f.arrays_zip('first', 'second').alias('zipped')).show(2,False)

+------------------------+
|zipped                  |
+------------------------+
|[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]|
+------------------------+
```

Comment: The above will only work for 2 arrays while `arrays_zip` works for any number of arrays.

Comment: This provides you the feasibility to assume the datatype being merged. And we can create this code dynamic anytime.

Comment: Can this be made dynamic, with a dynamic set of columns, not fixed as above?

Comment: Using the current function with an Array gives the error: `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use f.array, but you have to get the values later by index not by column name (that's the only difference).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = df.withColumn('combined', f.array(f.col('col1'), f.col('col2'), f.col('col3')))
```